# Altering "argument variables" without return and global variables

Tags: javascript, function, scope, arguments

```
var x = 0;
var f = function(arg1, arg2) {
    arg1 += 5;
    arg2 += 7;
//    return ?;
};
fill(255, 0, 0);
text(f(x, x), 200, 200);
```

As you can see, I can return just one variable, but considering that I'm working with more than one variable, I don't want to use return. The problem is: I want a generic and independent function, so I really DON'T want to declare global variables (in this case, arg1 and arg2) outside the scope of the function.

Is there any way of passing a value to the function and altering without return and without declaring global variables?

I thank you very much.

Comment: You could return an array or an object.

Comment: `return { result1: arg1+5, result2: arg2+7 };`

Comment: Technically you can "pass the arguments by reference" using closure, but that's no better than global variables.

Comment: Pass an object or array and modify it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in your values wrapped in an array or an object, and modify them there.

```
function modify(arrInput, objInput) {
  arrInput[0] += 10;
  objInput.x += 10;
};

var myArray = [1,2,3];
var myObject = { x: 0, y: 2, z: 4};
modify(myArray, myObject);
```

The result is now

```
myArray -> [11, 2, 3];
myObject -> { x: 10, y: 2, z: 4};
```

Of course, whether this makes sense at all depends on what you're trying to achieve, and since you haven't stated the purpose of your code, this is pretty much academic. You *can* do this, but usually it's a weird thing to do unless your functions act as a factory line that take some object, and tack on functionality or modify property as if your object is running down an assembly line in a factory.